# How can I undo replace all in visual studio code?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I was working on a Flutter project and by mistake I replaced 16 with 19 across all files, and now I am getting errors... How can I undo this.. Please someone help me!

Comment: Press on your keyboard Ctrl + Z. This is why we use [Git](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: It is not working mate I tried

Comment: you don't have any backup system with multiple versions? Search all 19 and go by hand to replace or all with 16

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Local History` and rollback to that version where you replaced 16 with 19.

`View` -> `Other Windows` -> `Local History`

Comment: In my VS Code, there isn't any option showing as Other WIndows under View.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio Code you are using?